# SULU CMS installation failed under homestead vagrant box

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead, sulu

I tried to install **SULU CMS** following this manual: http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started.html but when go to http://sulu.app/website.php (my local dev URL) I got these errors:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.ro_routes' doesn't exist in /home/vagrant/Code/sulu/app/Resources/views/master.html.twig on line 18
>   **Twig_Error_Runtime:** An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You need to be logged in for this operation"). in /home/vagrant/Code/sulu/app/Resources/views/master.html.twig on line 18

Before that all installation steps went well and I have seen no errors.

Also I have empty table in mysql database after this command:

> bin/adminconsole sulu:build prod

This is my **parameters.yml** file:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install

parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 33060 
    database_name: homestead
    database_user: homestead
    database_password: secret
    database_version: 5.5
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    sulu_admin.name: Sulu
    sulu_admin.email: null
    websocket_port: 9876
    websocket_url: sulu.lo
    phpcr_backend:
    type: doctrinedbal
    phpcr_workspace: default
    phpcr_user: admin
    phpcr_pass: admin
    phpcr_cache: file_system
```

I use homestead vagrant box v.5.,
Host machine Ubuntu 16.04,
Virtualbox v.5

And this is my Homestead.yaml content (all standard options):

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:

    - map: sulu.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/sulu/web


 databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Any ideas why and how to solve?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your database port in the parameters.yml file is 33060 instead of 3306 (the mysql default port), could that be the reason? Or have you configured mysql to run on a different port?

Comment: @DanielRotter, thanks for your reply! The problem was wrong database version mentioned in parameters.yml file (database_version: 5.5).

Comment: In that case I have also added an answer saying that, would be nice if you could accept it, so that this question is marked as solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong database port in your `parameters.yml`. It should be `3306` instead of `33060`.

Comment: I am using Laravel Homestead, it's recommended to use 33060 mysql port: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead but I'll try to use default 3306 also. Thanks!

Comment: m.s.: In that case you also have to configure the same database_port in the `app/config/parameters.yml` file.